# Ruby convert Url parameters to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this url encoded:

```
Started PUT "/path/thing/9812/close?status=close&shutdown_on=2018-12-05%2010%3A08%3A06&affected_external_id=15027&fqdns%5B0%5D=150.212.3.249"
```

which decoded is this:

```
"/path/thing/9812/close?status=close&shutdown_on=2018-12-05 10:08:06&affected_external_id=15027&fqdns[0]=150.212.3.249"
```

I get this parameters:

```
 Parameters: {"status"=>"close", "shutdown_on"=>"2018-12-05 10:08:06", "affected_external_id"=>"15027", "fqdns"=>{"0"=>"150.212.3.249"}, "id"=>"9812"}
```

How can get fqdn as a array? on Rails 4

Comment: Can you elaborate more or provide deep example case?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
params[:fqdns].to_a
```

Doing this, will produce the following:

```
{['0', '150.212.3.249', ...]}
```

If you wnat only the values, may you can try:

```
params[:fqdns].values
```

Doing this, will give you the following:

```
['150.212.3.249', ...]
```

But for this, you have to do it inside a ruby class, i strongly recommends you to do it inside your controller. Hope i can help.

UPDATE

After a recommends, you can do it with [strong parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), permiting the param `fqdns` as a hash (because you route receiving a hash):

```
 def resource_params 
  params.permit(....., fqdns: {})
 end
```

After this, you already have to execute the solutions above to get `fqsnd` as a array

Comment: You can not get the job done with strong parameters?, or some tool?,it seems that I can only use hash methods

Comment: He wnats to convert a hash to array, strong params it's a whitelist of params no? They can't change the value or the type of the param. But he can change the form to get a array instead of a hash too